# TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable - Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

New to python here and keep running into an error when trying to set up some code to scrape data off a list of web pages.

The link to one of those pages is - https://rspo.org/members/2.htm
and I am trying to grab the information on there like 'Membership Number', 'Category', 'Sector', 'Country', etc and export it all into a spreadsheet.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

pages = []

for i in range(1, 10):
    url = 'https://rspo.org/members/' + str(i)
    pages.append(url)


for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = soup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    member = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"current"})
```

And I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in 
>           soup = soup(page.text, 'html.parser')
>
> TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable

Not sure why I am getting this error. I tried looking at other pages on Stack Overflow but nothing seemed to have a similar error to the one I get above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have a name conflict because you are using the same name in multiple ways. Thus, your `soup` sets to a `BeautifulSoup` soup object, but is then reused as this same object.

Try this instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

pages = []

for i in range(1, 10):
    url = 'https://rspo.org/members/' + str(i)
    pages.append(url)


for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    member = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"current"})
```

Note that I just removed the alias from `BeautifulSoup`. The reason why I took this approach is simple. The standard convention in Python is that classes should be proper case. I.e `ClassOne` and `BeautifulSoup`. Instances of classes should be lower-case i.e `class` and `soup`. This helps avoid name conflicts, but it also makes your code more intuitive. Once you learn this, it becomes much easier to read code, and to write **clean** code.

Comment: Thanks Brandon! Appreciate the info on cases.